# Registering gcmregistrar.getregistrationid returns empty ID

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello Android developers.

I have 2 Android applications with 2 different packages.
I want to register both of my applications to Google.
I have registered my apps using the same method.
And both of my applications have GCMActivity ( All of you already know the code, I used the same code as all of you ).

But i am stuck in a condition where one of my applications can't get regId.

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

I tried to debug my apps, and what I got is this :
Application A gets the regId, but Application B only has "" value.

I don't understand what the problem is.
Both of them have similar code, similar way to register to Google.
Only different packages, SENDER_ID, GCMBroadcastReceiver, and Android key.

Is there a way my apps can get regId.
It has been like a week, I tried to register it using different Google accounts and different PC's.
But same result. I really need help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> All of you already know the code, I used the same code as all of you

You are wrong about that. You are using old and deprecated code. Beside the issue of `GCMRegistrar` being deprecated, `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)` doesn't register to GCM, it just retrieves the registration ID that was previously persisted in SharedPreferences after a successful registration. If this method returns an empty registration ID, you should register to GCM (which is done with GCMRegistrar.register()).

You should, however, switch to using the GoogleCloudMessaging.register method of the Google Play Services library.

Comment: I already done that in many way. It works in my Application A. Why you saying that i'm using an old and deprecated code if my other apps working.